# Changes in included file not registering in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cc

I am on Arch Linux. I have tried gcc and cc.

I have quite a strange problem. I have a file included from /usr/include (installed from an Arch package) in a C program like so.

```
// prog.c
#include <foobar/foobar.h>
```

When I change it, nothing happens. Let me explain. It includes some C code.

```
// foobar/foobar.h
int baz = 1, qux = 2;
```

Recently, it has been updated.

```
// foobar/foobar.h
int baz = 1, qux = 2, norf = 3;
```

My test program looks something like what follows.

```
// prog.c
#include <foobar/foobar.h>
printf ("%d %d %d\n", baz, qux, norf);
```

output:

```
error: ‘norf’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I can duplicate the file in the same directory, name it foobar2.h, and then include that file instead and it outputs:

```
1 2 3
```

So the path is not incorrect. I can make a link to the folder, name it foobar2, and include foobar2/foobar.h and it outputs:

```
1 2 3
```

So the file is not incorrect.

To confirm that it is not registering changes, I can destroy the foobar folder entirely and try to print just the 2 variables that were originally inside the header. This outputs:

```
1 2
```

Clearly something is not updating. The same behaviour is displayed when I try updating the file with enums, functions, or new values for existing items in the file, and include them as the only lines in the file. None of the changes register. The same activity is displayed with gcc and cc. This has been going on a few months now and it still has not resolved itself.

Comment: If you believe that this has something to do with the library itself, I have some details here: http://pastebin.com/Mhj4jfFr

Comment: I would try including this file using quotation marks. Maybe your system caches library includes for faster compilation.

Comment: You need to build each time before you link?

Comment: @Anonymous Putting it in quotations does work. So my system possibly does cache libraries. I found a file mentioning the libary ld.so.cache and removed it, but that did not fix my problem.

Comment: What package - I can verify on my Arch box (community/python-tox)?

Comment: @AhmedHamdy Please clarify.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the package is tox-git and any tox client, the details are in the pastebin in the first comment. You will not get these results, which is why I chose an abstract example to display the actual problem, but you can try.

Comment: So, do quotaion marks satisfy you?

Comment: @Anonymous It's a very good solution, but I wouldn't like to have to edit every package that uses the tox-git library every time I update them. I would like to disable or update the cache.

Comment: Ok, I'd also try to disable precompiled header usage during compilation, can you do that?

Comment: In searching for a precompiled header, I tried to get gcc to print all included files. I found that it was using a version of the folder in /usr/local/include.
This is highly embarassing... I'm not sure why I didn't think of this. I hope someone benefits from my mistake.

Comment: If you're using `gcc`, use `gcc -H` to print the list of header files being included.  You will find that the `foobar/foobar.h` that is actually being included is not the one you edited or thought was being included.

Comment: Yes, gcc -H is what I used to find this problem. If you are having this issue it is the first thing you should try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file does not seem to be updating, it is a good idea to check other places on your system where your compilers search for libraries for identically named folders. In this case, it was in /usr/local/include, where I had a version that I compiled and forgot about entirely.

Comment: Newbie here -- is there any order of precedence with the system default search paths?  Was the older version in a folder that was getting searched first?

Comment: According to the gcc manual section 3.19, include paths specified with -B, -I, -L, and other command line options take precedence over include paths specified using environment variables, which take precedence over include paths set by gcc configuration. In _An Introduction to GCC_ section 3.1, it says that the order of searching for headers is /usr/local/include then /usr/include, and the order for libraries is /usr/local/lib then /usr/lib.

Answer (score 0):

This can be mainly due to the include directory path mismatch. Check out the environment variable that can affect the behavior like `C_INCLUDE_PATH` , `CPATH`. Another option would be to check with `gcc -I/src/directory foobar.h` while compilation that can lead you closer to the problem or use `#include "foobar.h"` in the code.

In case if there are multiple copies of the program in your system, it is possible that completely different file is used for compilation and execution which can also lead to changes not getting reflected.